# sort associative array codeigniter php

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, sorting

Here is what I want to do:

```
$newArray = array();

foreach($student as $s){
    $newArray[$s->id][$s->grade] = $s;
}
```

I want to sort the students by their grades (more of a group than a sort) but I just want the grades to be sorted not the id. I could have don't this:

```
$newArray[$s->id] = $s->grade 
asort($newArray)
```

but I need the remaining data in `$s`. Also, there is huge chunk of data associated with each student which I want to maintain.

How can I achieve such a sorting?

Comment: I think it fair to say that the data is coming from a db, why not `ORDER BY grade DESC`?

Comment: naah , thats not the case here

Comment: I've updated my answer, and provided a full, tested and working example of how to use uasort in a class. It _should_ work, well it does for me, at least (working in php 5.2 and 5.3)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Edit:*

Sine you're working in a framework, best declare your sort callback as a member function (inside the same class as where you'll be needing it, of course):

```
private function sortCB(array $a, array $b)
{//the array type hinting in arguments is optional
    $i = array_keys($a);//but highly recommended 
    $j = array_keys($b);
    if (end($i) === end($j))
    {
        return 0;
    }
    //replace '>' with '<' if you want to sort descending
    return (end($i) > end($j) ? 1 : -1);//this is ascending
}
```

Then, in the method where the actual sorting is needed:

```
uasort($theArray,array($this,'sortCB'));
```

For more examples, see [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php). I've added a full class example at the end of this (bulky) answer

---

I've tried this on [writecodeonline](http://writecodeonline.org/php), which isn't all too good at this kind of stuff, but this did work:

```
$foo = array_fill_keys(array('foo','bar','q','Bond'),array());
$i = '256';
foreach($foo as $k=>$v)
{
    $foo[$k][$i] = $k;
    $i = (string)((int)$i%2 === 0 ? ((int)$i/2)+1 : (int)$i*3);
}
function sortCB($a,$b)
{
    $i = array_keys($a);
    $j = array_keys($b);
    if (end($i) === end($j))
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return (end($i) > end($j) ? 1 : -1);
}
uasort($foo,'sortCB');
var_dump($foo);
```

But since you're using a framework, you might do well declaring that function as a member function `private function sortCB(array $a,array $b)`, and use it like so:

```
uasort($foo,array($this, 'sortCB'));
```

There might be some more info on how best to use this callback function in a class context [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php)

---

Full example + usage (tested and working):

```
class test
{
    public $foo = null;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->foo = array_fill_keys(array('foo','bar','q','Bond'),array());
        $i = '256';
        foreach($this->foo as $k=>$v)
        {
            $this->foo[$k][$i] = $k;
            $i = (string)((int)$i%2 === 0 ? ((int)$i/2)+1 : (int)$i*3);
        }
    }
    private function sortCB($a,$b)
    {
        $i = array_keys($a);
        $j = array_keys($b);
        if (end($i) === end($j))
        {
            return 0;
        }
        return (end($i) > end($j) ? 1 : -1);
    }
    public function sortFoo()
    {
        uasort($this->foo,array($this,'sortCB'));
        print_r($this->foo);
        return $this->foo;
    }
}
$bar = new test();
$arr = $bar->sortFoo();
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like:

```
foreach($student as $s){
    $newArray[$s->id] = $s;
}

usort($newArray, function ($a, $b) { return $a->grade - $b->grade; });
```

### Edit

For later versions that don't support anonymous functions you can define comparison function first:

```
function sortByGrade($a, $b)
{
    return $a->grade - $b->grade;
}

usort($newArray, 'sortByGrade');
```

But if you get this data from db it would be easier to order it in your sql query. If you use ORM you can use its associated method.

Comment: would codeigniter allow that , what uv done inside the usort function ?

Comment: @user1537158 codeigniter is framework written in php, so it can't prohibit php doing something that's supported by it. The only limitation can be php version.

Comment: aaah not supported  , my IDE gives me a bright red line below the usort function

Comment: @user1537158 IDE is editor how does it know which version is on the server? If you use PHP >5 this will work fine.

Comment: anonymous functions might not be supported by your php version, just define the function like any other (`function sortCB($a,$b){...}` and use `usort($newArray,'sortCB');`

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem tried that too , php throws me an error saying the function defination is not found or is wrong

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem php throws me this : "usort() expects parameter 2 to be a valid callback, function 'sortByTerritory' not found or invalid function name" i have taken care of the spelling and the case for the function but usort doesnt seem to work

Comment: @PLB even for the edited version of ur answer i get the php error "usort() expects parameter 2 to be a valid callback, function 'sortByTerritory' not found or invalid function name"

Comment: @user1537158 Have you renamed function `sortByGrade` to `sortByTerritory`? If you've just copied my function won't work because it has different name.

Comment: in codeigniter should be calling the sortByGrade using this ? @PLB

Comment: @PLB sure i have taken care of that

Comment: @user1537158: where are you declaring the function? inside the member function, or as a new member function of your class? if the latter, check my answer: call it by `uasort($theArr,array($this,'callbackName');`<-- pass reference to the current object, too. If the first: don't, create a new member function, and call it with the `array($this,'')` thingy. I'll update my answer to show you what I mean

Comment: @user1537158 define your callback outside of controller class in the same file.

Comment: @PLB that works , even Elias Van Ootegem's solution worked , thank you both , kudos