# codeigniter model can't find usort routine.

Tags: php, codeigniter, sorting, usort

I have a model in my codeigniter app with the following callback function used by usort:

```
    function comp_primary($a, $b) 
    {
            if ($a['pri'] == $b['pri']) {
                    return $a['weight'] - $b['weight'];
            }
            return strcmp($a['pri'], $b['weight']);
    }
```

I call it from the same model, just in a different method like so:

```
 usort($srv_records, 'comp_primary')
```

The error message I'm getting is:

> Severity: Warning  --> usort() expects parameter 2 to be a valid
>   callback, function 'comp_primary' not found or invalid function name
>   /var/www/html/widgets/manager/models/widget_model.php 187

I've tried to change the function signature on comp_primary to look like this:

```
private function comp_primary($a, $b)
```

I also tried to change the way I call it, like so:

```
 usort($srv_records, '$this->comp_primary');
```

or

```
  usort($srv_records, $this->comp_primary);
```

Can you tell me what I'm missing? Thanks!

Comment: Please check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12197345/sort-associative-array-codeigniter-php

Comment: @u_mulder, that's a useless comment.  1. the first argument is supposed to be the array.  2. did it occur to you that people may have tried reading the manual and are asking because they don't understand?  If you're gonna take the time to comment, provide a useful answer.  otherwise, don't bother.

Comment: thanks @shuvo. if you want to post as answer, i will accept. thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Please try with this one :

```
usort($srv_records, array($this,'comp_primary'));
```

For more information , please see [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php)

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks.